# php cli: unexpected T_USE

Tags: php

I've got the following code which I want to run from CLI:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require '/usr/share/nginx/www/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;

$ec2Client = Ec2Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
));
```

Am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE on line 5

The line that is causing the error is:

```
use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;
```

Is it not possible to import like this when using CLI?

**Edit**

PHP version:

> PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012
>   19:00:27)

Comment: What version of PHP are you running on the command line?

Comment: try `use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client as Ec2Client;` ?

Comment: @eis still getting same error

Comment: What if you move `use` line to the very top? PS: only `use` without `require` as suggested below

Answer (score 1):

`use` statements should appear at the top of code - directly after the PHP tag open (or a `namespace` definition), or as the first lines in a class.

For an example of such a bug (solved) see https://github.com/browscap/browscap-php/issues/1#issuecomment-22737388